# How can I remotely connect to a Linux terminal session

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm looking for some way of granting terminal access to a Linux machine from outside of the network. I know I can do a remote SSH tunneling from a firewalled machine to an outside server, with SSH port exposed, but if I do it that way, I'll need to know a user name and password for the machine.

What I'm looking for is, if a guy can access the machine locally (maybe using SSH or sitting in front of the screen), then he can run some command to connect this session to a remote server (which I manage), and then both can work on the same terminal session, run commands and similar stuff, without knowing his password, maybe until he kills the session or the command. Something like a TeamViewer or AnyDesk, but just for console sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but have you looked at 'screen'?

Here is a good explanation of screen:  http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/screen/